# Unable to import timezonefinder

Tags: python

I'm unable to import the timezonefinder Python library:

```
>>> import timezonefinder
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/timezonefinder/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/timezonefinder/timezonefinder.py", line 300
        def closest_timezone_at(self, *, lat, lng, delta_degree=1, exact_computation=False, return_distances=False,
                                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer [address your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

[Timezonefinder](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder) supports Python 3 only.  You're using Python 2.

One immediate piece of evidence is that the syntax `def f(a, *, b=xyz)` is not valid in Python 2, as shown in your traceback.

You can always check a package's [`setup.py`](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder/blob/96cc43afb3bae57ffd002ab4cf104fe15eda2257/setup.py#L58), which (should) hint at `'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only'` for this limitation.